# How increment and decrement with if condition

Tags: java, increment

I have this code:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 99;

        if (x++ == x) {
            System.out.println("x++==x : " + x);
        }

        if (++x == x ) {
            System.out.println("++x==x : " + x); // ++x == x : 101
        }

        if (x == x++) {
            System.out.println("x==x++ : " + x); //x==x++ : 102
        }

        if (x == ++x) {
            System.out.println("x==++x : " + x);
        }

        if (++x == ++x) {
            System.out.println("++x==++x : " + x);
        }

        if (x++ == x++) {
            System.out.println("x++==x++ : " + x);
        }

        if (++x == x++) {
            System.out.println("++x==x++ : " + x); // ++x==x++ : 109
        }           
    }
}
```

and this is the output -->

```
++x==x : 101
x==x++ : 102
++x==x++ : 109
```

I want to figure out how the java compiler handles this code. I could figure out how it came up with this part of the output:

```
++x==x : 101
x==x++ : 102
```

But I couldn't with this part of the output:

```
++x==x++ : 109
```

How does this code work? And most importantly how does the last output work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to know 3 things and use logic to put it together:

1. `x++` means: "Increment x, but the expression's value is what x was before you increment".
2. `++x` means: "Increment x, and the expression's value is what x is *after* you increment".
3. Things resolve left to right for the `==` operator. So, java 'resolves' the thing on the left, then the thing on the right, then does the calculation.

Thus, given: `++x==x++`, and let's say `x` starts out as 107. Let's break it down:

1. First, resolve the left side, which is `++x`. To do that, increment (`x` is now 108), then resolve the expression as the  value *after* increment. So, the left hand side is `108`.
2. Next resolve right side, which is `x++`. To do that, increment (`x` is now 109), then resolve the expression as the value *before* increment. So, the right hand side is `108`.
3. Now do the operation. `108 == 108`. That's `true`, so the if 'passes', and the result is printed. Given that `x` is now 109, it would print "++x==x++ : 109".

Which is exactly what it does.

Comment: @Madhura Copy/paste this answer, replacing "before" with "after". It sounds suspiciously like your question is: "Can you explain these too so I can not read it and just paste it into this homework folder and get a passing grade". Stop being lazy.

Answer (score 1):

`++x` is pre-increment
`x++` is post-increment

Even if your condition gets a false, the incrementing will be done.